# AS3 - AIR - From a swf path file to a ByteArray

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash, arrays

I am coding an AIR application.

I've got directly a path of a swf file (because it was stored in a xml file).
Do yo know if it is possible to get the ByteArray from this file ?

I know that FileReference do that very well, but this class need a select event. But it isn't my case because I've allready got my path.

Thanks a lot for your answers !

Comment: `FileReference.load()` can be caused only by certain user action (click, press)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AIR, you can read/write files directly using [`flash.filesystem.File`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) and [`flash.filesystem.FileStream`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html).

See, for example, [this article](http://blog.everythingflex.com/2008/02/25/file-and-filestream-within-air/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Here is my code:
`var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var swfFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(fullSWFPath);
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(swfFile, FileMode.READ);
**stream.readBytes(byteArray);**
stream.close();`

Answer (score 0):

however you can load it with [`URLStream`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html) and get a `ByteArray` with [`URLStream.readBytes()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html#readBytes%28%29)

Comment: Thank you too for you answer :)